# Export kibana monitoring

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a hard time finding out how I export kibana monitoring, triggers and even destination configuration. Is it possible to do from the UI? Are there any other options?

Cheers,
Rasmus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a little script that seems to work and does what I want (export from one, import into another environment) https://gist.github.com/MrMjauh/e0af060fecb7186b34799b476a1cd0c8

It is only tested with Kibana 7.1.1 management